# How to include a modified version of a package in Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a project where I'm using a Docker container to install the packages needed for running. I am trying to include a modified version of a python library/package.

The modified version is basically the same package with some lines of the source code removed/modified. Is there a way to include this in my Docker container/project? The problem is that every time I run `RUN pip install desired_package` I would get the original version, what I want is the my modified version.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `COPY` the modified code into a layer of the container and then `python -m pip install path/to/code`.

Comment: Alternatively, push the modified code to github or a similar git hosting service. Then you can specify to install it from their instead of pypi.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice how would I do that (second part not pushing to GitHub). Sorry I’m new to Docker

Comment: @skidjoe This part isn't specific to docker. I suggest googling something like "pip install from github" to find some suggestions how to do it.